# Using mail() to send multiple emails from MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, email

I got this code and it's old and I know I need to convert it to PDO (still learning) but I need to get this working right now.

I am trying to send multiple emails out based on the query.  So in this particular query I get two results.  So I need to send out two different emails to the group.  If the query had 4 results, then I would need to send 4. Right now it is only sending the first result.  How can I get it to loop through and send multiple emails.

Here is the code:

```
<?
// connection string ......

$production = "SELECT value1 FROM parameters WHERE name = 'IS_PRODUCTION' ";

$query = "SELECT accounts.username, email_activate.email, accounts.user_id, accounts.alt_id FROM accounts INNER JOIN email_activate ON accounts.user_id = email_activate.user_id WHERE dt_welcome = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND dt_start <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


$message =  "Hello ".$row['username'].", <br/><br/>";
$message .=  "You recently subscribed to <bblah blah blah</b> ";
$message .=  '(<a href="http://">http://</a>), ' ;
$message .=  "the official ";
$message .=  "source of <br /><br /> ";

if ($production == 'Y' ) {


$subject = "How can we Assist!";
$to = "".$row['email']."";
$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE email_activate SET dt_welcome = NOW() WHERE user_id = '".$row['user_id']."' ");



} else {

$subject = "[TEST] Offer You Assistance";
$to      = 'email1@email.com' . ', ';
$to      .= 'email2@email.com ' . ', ';
$to      .= 'email3@email.com';


$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE email_activate SET dt_welcome = NOW() WHERE user_id = '".$row['user_id']."' ");

}



$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";


$queryEmail = "SELECT alt_id FROM lookup_roles WHERE spec_tag = 'public_email'";
$result3 = mysql_query($queryEmail) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row12 = mysql_fetch_array($resul3t)) {


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f ".$row12[alt_id]."");

}

}

?>
```

So I fixed it, the above code works just fine.  I forgot to use a different $result variable ---> Changed it from $result to $result3, this way it doesn't blank out the previous result which is why I was only getting 1 email.  I knew it was something simple, just couldn't see it.

Comment: how many results do you get with '$queryEmail = "SELECT alt_id FROM lookup_roles WHERE spec_tag = 'public_email'";' ?

Comment: I get one, but that's not the query I'm having a problem with.  The query I'm having issues with is the $query one.  I get 2 results but it should email 2 emails but it only emails 1.